# HTML page doesn't work as HTA Changes month of date object to zero

Tags: javascript, html, hta

I have no problem with the following page as an html file: [interest calculator](http://home.comcast.net/~wporter211/realsite/testint.html), but if you save its source as an **hta** and run it, then choose "Gen P.I. in new window", you will get garbage for the first month in the P.I. display.  The alerts show the month in html but will be zero in the hta and the first month may be "0-1" on the P.I.

I wasn't able to format the calculate function, please check the above link.

```
function   payEntry(month,day,year,payment,interest,appPrin,principal,frontEnd){
            this.month=month;
            this.day=day;
            this.year=year;
            this.payment=payment;
            this.interest=interest;
            this.appPrin=appPrin;
            this.principal=principal;
            this.frontEnd=frontEnd;
 //         if (isNaN(month))
 //           alert(payTable.length + " in payEntry");
    }
function calculate() {
var lastTarget, sumPayments, workPrincipal, i, firstInt=0;
var tPayment, tInterest, tAppPrin;
fpmmG = parseInt(document.loandata.fpmm.value);
alert(fpmmG + " in calculate");
principal = parseFloat(document.loandata.principal.value);
interest = parseFloat(document.loandata.interest.value) / 100 / 12;
if (isNaN(interest))
  return;
daysDiff = parseInt(document.loandata.NoDays.value) - 30;
```

I guess the problem is not being able to read the "fpmm" field from the formatted screen.  As far as I know I haven't had problems reading any other field.  This is part of the displayed screen:

```
<td width="20">5)</td>
  <td width="260">1<sup>st</sup> Payment MM DD YY:</td>
  <td>
    <pre><input type="text" name="fpmm" size="2" ></pre>
  </td>
  <td>
    <pre><input type="text" name="fpdd" size="2" ></pre>
  </td>
  <td>
    <pre><input type="text" name="fpyy" size="2" ></pre>
```

TIA

Comment: Please add the _relevant_ code to the post.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask here

Comment: I would think the issue is in function genpi and not in payentry which does nothing

Comment: The posted code snippet is not relevant to the question. Try to isolate the problem into few lines and create an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with which we can re-produce your issue.

Answer (score 0):

The page worked when I read the month of first payment (and put it in a global variable) on startup and in the "ExtraDays" function, both of whom calculate the month.  In the calculate() function, the value of that global is read, not the page itself.

Still don't know why it worked that way.